Minimum number of triangles in a graph with at least $\lfloor\frac{n^2}{4}\rfloor + 1$ edges (Erdös-Rademacher Theorem)
Let $G$ be a graph on $n$ vertices. Show that if $G$ has at least $\lfloor\frac{n^2}{4}\rfloor+1$ edges, then $G$ contains at least $\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor$ triangles.
I have been trying to understand a proof for this that uses induction and removes two vertices as can be found here for Problem 1.
Up until the point where we establish by induction that $G-x-y$ cointains at least $\lfloor\frac{n-2}{2}\rfloor$ triangles, everything seems clear to me. However, I don't understand how we proceed from the moment the proof states that one of $N(x)$ and $N(y)$ must contain an edge. I fail to see reason why there must be an edge in $N(x)$ and $N(y)$. For example, what do we do if $N(x), N(y) \leq 1$ or all the edges in $G-x-y$ "fit" in $G-x-y$ without connecting any of the vertices in $N(x)$ or $N(y)$? From the explanation in the proof I don't understand why this seems to always be the case?
I can see why there must be such edge in $N(x)$ or $N(y)$ if all vertices either belong to $N(x)$ or $N(y)$, however, as I understand this must not be the case and thus I need more clarification onto why this is supposed to be the case. Any help is appreciated. If anyone has alternative proof, that would be great too, as I can't seem to find anything.

I assume $n>2$?

I assume so. The induction started on $n=3$.

"Up until the point where we establish by induction that $\mathit{−−}$ cointains at least $\mathit{\lfloor\frac{n-2}{2}\rfloor}$ triangles, everything seems clear to me." So let's start from the sentence which immediately follows...
But the number of edges between $N(x)$ and $N(y)$ is at most $\lfloor\frac{(n-2)^2}{4}\rfloor$. From the statement two sentences prior, we know that $|E(G-x-y)|=\lfloor\frac{(n-2)^2}{4}\rfloor+1$. Furthermore, if it were the case that $|E(N(x))|$$+\ |E(N(y))|>\lfloor\frac{(n-2)^2}{4}\rfloor$, then we would reach a contraction $(n>5)$: $$\scriptsize|E(G)|=|E(N(x))|+|E(N(y))|+|E(G-x-y)|>2\lfloor\frac{(n-2)^2}{4}\rfloor+1>\lfloor\frac{(n-2)^2}{4}\rfloor+1+(n-1)=|E(G)|.$$
Therefore, it is necessary that $|E(N(x))|+|E(N(y))|\leq\lfloor\frac{(n-2)^2}{4}\rfloor$. The rest of the proof should follow from this. Let me know if you have any additional questions.

Notation. $E(G)$ denotes the collection of all edges for a given graph $G$.

By $|E(N(x))|+|E(N(y))| \leq \lfloor \frac{(n−2)^2}{4}\rfloor$ you mean the number of edges between $N(x)$ and $N(y)$ is at most $\lfloor \frac{(n−2)^2}{4}\rfloor$? That I understand. But not all vertices in $G-x-y$ must be in $N(x)$ or $N(y)$, right? Shouldn't it then be possible for $G-x-y$ to have at least $\lfloor \frac{(n−2)^2}{4}\rfloor + 1$ edges, as stated, while at the same time there is no edge in $N(x)$ and $N(y)$ respectively? It seems to me that it it concluded that there is ALWAYS an edge in $N(x)$ or $N(y)$, but I don't understand why.

@ninaPh99 The reason why it is fine to assume that all vertices of $G$ will share a vertex with either $x$ xor $y$ can be thought of in this way. Consider arbitrary graph $G’$ with $N>n$ vertices. Consider the subgraph $G=N(x)\cup N(y)$, and assume that it’ll have $n$ many vertices, and contains at least […] many edges. Then…(proof should be a little more clear from this).
